can we build sequential model?
Like is it possible to train a model on X1_i Inputs Y1_i Output and then the second one is running on X1_i + Y1_i to give output Y2_i ??
Context : (I am just getting my hand into ML and trying to build this for a product where we are predicting what the user is likely to select. I have learned about Supervised Learning Algorithims including ensemble techniques, so if there's another thing to learn kindly suggest) so Like building api's with flask would it be possible to get those result ??

Yes, absolutely. Learn linear regression.
